# SQLAlchemy ORM DateTime with specific format

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, format

I have a table which stores a datetime value in the following format: (e.g.) 20160213145512. Unfortunately, SQLAlchemy gives me no chance to specify the format used to store a datetime value into the database with sqlalchemy´s DateTime type.

Therefore, i have created the following dataype:

```
class Timestamp(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String(14)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, datetime):
            value = '%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d' % (value.year,
                                                  value.month,
                                                  value.day,
                                                  value.hour,
                                                  value.minute,
                                                  value.second)
        return value


    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value:
            return datetime(year=int(value[0:4]),
                            month=int(value[4:6]),
                            day=int(value[6:8]),
                            hour=int(value[8:10]),
                            minute=int(value[10:12]),
                            second=int(value[12:14])
                            )
```

I do not use strftime and strptime for performance reasons.
What I am now able to do is the following:

```
class TestTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TESTTABLE"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(Timestamp)
```

Insert row by defining the datetime via a datetime object:

```
session.add(TestTable(timestamp=datetime(year=2016, month=2, day=3, hour=2)))
```

Or inserting a row by defining datetime as a string:

```
session.add(TestTable(timestamp="20160203031422"))
```

So far, so good. 
But the following is not working as expected:

```
session.query(TestTable).filter(TestTable.timestamp.year == 2016).all()
```

If I am runnning this code snippet I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with ORDERS.dz_statakt has an attribute 'year'
```

However this works:

```
session.query(TestTable).filter(TestTable.timestamp.startswith("2016")).all()
```

Until now I was not able to solve this problem. I guess I am missing something in my own Timestamp class.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but a little convoluted.

First, the reason why your code doesn't work. `TestTable.timestamp` is a `Column`. There is no `year` attribute defined anywhere. The `year` attribute is on the `datetime` object that you return from `process_result_value`. The reason `TestTable.timestamp.startswith` works is because `.startswith` is a [considered an operator by SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.startswith).

So, to make it work, you'll need to define attributes on `TestTable.timestamp` that gives you correct SQL expression when you compare them against values:

```
class Timestamp(TypeDecorator):
    impl = String(14)

    class comparator_factory(TypeDecorator.Comparator, impl.comparator_factory):
        @property
        def year(self):
            return cast(func.substr(self.expr, 1, 4), Integer)

        ...

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        ...

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        ...
```

Comment: One note: Better to derive comparator_factory from String.Comparator. Otherwise string functions like startswith have a strange behaviour.

Comment: @Rollmops Thanks. The original `TypeDecorator.comparator_factory` actually derives from `(TypeDecorator.Comparator, impl.comparator_factory)`. I've updated my answer.